# Find a Jordan canonical basis for the transformation $T(f) = f + f'$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I am making this problem far harder than it needs to be. Here is the statement: for each non-negative integer $n$, let $P_n$ be the space of real-valued polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$. Find a Jordan Canonical basis for the map $T(f) = f' + f$.

My attempt: I let $\beta = \{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$, the standard basis for $P_n$. Then, we have

$${\left[ T \right]_\beta } = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&0& \ldots &0\\
0&1&2&0& \ldots &0\\
0&0&1&3& \ldots &0\\
0&0&0&1& \ldots &0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&0& \cdots &{n - 1}\\
0&0&0&0& \ldots &1
\end{array}} \right],$$

so the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $c_T(t) = (1-t)^{n+1}$. So, our only eigenvalue is $1$, and the multiplicity of the eigenvalue is $n+1$.

Now, I'm lost. I believe that the Jordan Canonical Form of $T$ is

$${J } = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&0& \ldots &0\\
0&1&1&0& \ldots &0\\
0&0&1&1& \ldots &0\\
0&0&0&1& \ldots &0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&0& \cdots &1\\
0&0&0&0& \ldots &1
\end{array}} \right],$$

but my normal method for finding a Jordan Canonical basis would be to try to take the standard basis, and figure out which one of those vectors was in $\ker((T-I)^{n+1}),$ but not in $\ker((T-I)^{n}$. But I think that $(T-I)^{n+1}$ is the zero matrix, so I have no idea how to deal with this problem from here, and it seems like maybe there should be a more clever way to figure this out...

Comment: instead of looking at the kernel of $(T - I)^{n+1}$ you need to look at the kernel of $(T-I)^j$ for $j$ between $1$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer requires only a small modification to adjust the constants:
$$
        \left\{ \frac{1}{0!}x^{0},\frac{1}{1!}x^{1},\frac{1}{2!}x^{2},\cdots,\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}\right\}.
$$
Then $(T-I)$ maps the first basis element to $0$, and maps the $(k+1)$-st basis element to the $k$-th basis element for $k > 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would be be able to provide some insight as to how to arrive at this conclusion? I see why this works, but I'm not sure how you came up with this coefficients and would love to get some insight on that!

Comment: @poppy3345 : Ignore the diagonal terms in a Jordan block. Subtracting away the diagonal part gives you a matrix $N$ that is nilpotent, and where $Ne_1 = 0, Ne_2 = e_1, Ne_3 = e_2,\cdots$ ($e_j$ are the standard basis elements.) So, if you take a cycle $x\mapsto Nx \mapsto N^{2}x \mapsto \cdots\mapsto N^{k-1}x\mapsto 0$ and reverse the order of the elements, you get a linearly independent set with respect to which $N$ is represented as a Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$. That's what differentiation does. $x^{n}\mapsto nx^{n-1}\mapsto \cdots\mapsto n!\mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over this question again, I've come up with a different answer that I thought might be helpful to those who look at it in the future. Here it is:

First, we will find the eigenvalues of $T$. We seek scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k$, where $1 \le k \le n$, such that for each $1\le i \le k$, we can find an $f \in \mathcal{P}_n$ such that
$$T(f) = \lambda_i f.$$
But $T(f) = f + f'$, and so we seek $\lambda_i$ and $f$ such that
$$f + f' = \lambda_i f.$$
This is a differential equation, which can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{df}{dt} = (\lambda_i - 1)f,$$
and solved using separation of variables, as follows:
$$\frac{1}{f}\ df = (\lambda_i - 1)dt$$
$$\ln(f) = (\lambda_i-1)t +c,$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant of integration, and finally we have
$$f = ke^{(\lambda_i-1)}t,$$
where $k = e^c$. These are all solutions that satisfy the differential equation; however, the only values of $\lambda_i$ for which $f \in \mathcal{P}_n$ is $\lambda_i = 1$. Thus, $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$.

Now that we have found an eigenvalue of $T$, we can show that any constant function, $f = c$, is an eigenvector: we have
$$T(c) = 0 + c = c.$$

Finally, we will now find a cycle of generalized eigenvectors of $T$. Consider $x^n$. We have:
$$(T-\lambda I)^nx^n = (T-I)^{n-1}(nx^{n-1}) = (T-I)^{n-2}(n(n-1)x^{n-2}) = \dots = (T-I)n! = 0,$$
so $x^n \in N(T-\lambda I)^n$. Thus, we have found a cycle of generalized eigenvectors of length $n+1$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. This means that the Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ is
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1& \ldots &0\\
0&1& \ldots &0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &1\\
0&0& \ldots &1
\end{array}} \right],$$
 the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix with $1$s on both the diagonal and super diagonal, and since the Jordan Canonical Form of $T$ must be $(n+1) \times (n+1)$, the above matrix is, in fact the Jordan Canonical form of $T$ itself.